# 500 Internal Server Error : An error occurred(0): Unknown data property field_group_privacy

Tags: nodes, organic-groups, services, 8, entities

I am trying to Create Services to Create Node Type Discussion in a Group using Services Module, but getting the error :

> 500 Internal Server Error : An error occurred(0): Unknown data property field_group_privacy

In the Header I have given:

> Content-type:application/json
>
> x-csrf-token:token value
>
> session-name:session name value

In the Body I have given :

```
{
"og_group_ref": {"und": [{"target_id": "3897"}]},

"title": "Title of discussion",

"field_description": {"und": [{"value": "test description"}]},

"type": "discussion"

}
```

Can anyone please tell me why I am getting this error ?

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: What module, field type and widget are used for your `field_group_privacy`?

Comment: field type is Boolean 
And Widget is Check boxes/radio buttons

This Field is in Groups, but I am trying to create Discussion in a particular Group.

Comment: If `field_group_privacy` is set to required, try changing it to optional to see what happens. I'd also use `grep -rn 'field_group_privacy' sites/all` to see what (if any) code is trying to tinker with that field. I'd also suspect any contrib module related to that field as well.

Comment: @tyler.frankenstein I activated syslog and its showing this error : **EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property field_group_privacy. in EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo() (line 335 of /home/content/34/10950234/html/***/***/sites/all/modules/contrib/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc)**

Comment: That's what I suspected as well. Go to that file and line number, and add this before it throws the new exception: `dpm(debug_backtrace());` (be sure to have the Devel module enabled). That will reveal to you what file and line of code is the problem maker (it prints out an array, and usually index `2` contains the file and line number.

Comment: @tyler.frankenstein I have enabled the module and added this code, but now where I can see the file and line of code ? I am using both POSTER and REST-CLIENT to send the request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30025/discussion-between-sara-and-tyler-frankenstein).

Comment: Use `watchdog('sara', '<pre>' . print_r(debug_backtrace(), true) . '</pre>');` instead of `dpm()`, sorry.